# How to select discrete cosine transform coefficients as a feature vector?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, image-processing

I need to use DCT on frames of videos as a feature vector to train a Feed-forward artificial neural network, but the problem is the large number of coefficients (in thousands or so). How can I choose some of these coefficients and still capture the majority of information for my image (frame)?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you consider to be relevant information, which in turn depends on what kind of image features you are interested in.

The coefficients of a DCT describe progressively finer-grained structure in an image. So if you're interested in relatively large-scale features of your image, such as moving objects in the foreground, you are likely only interested in the low-frequency coefficients. On the other hand, if you are interested in small-scale features, such as the texture of materials, the high-frequency components are much more relevant. The figure below (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform)) shows the various components of the DCT, ranging from low-frequency in the top left, to high frequency in the bottom right.

[image]

As a quick and dirty approach, it's most likely that the information you're looking for is encapsulated in the first few low-frequency coefficients. You can try setting a cut-off $K$ and only accepting coefficients $X_{i,j}$ where $i^2 + j^2 < K$. The appropriate value of this cut-off can be determined either by trial and error, or by cross-validation.

Comment: I am really looking for the low-frequency coefficients, because my project is about sign language recognition, so I look for the shape and position of each hand rather than any fine details. Does the proposed approach work after the zigzag coding or doesn't need any prior modification of the arrangement of coefficients at all?.

Comment: The arrangement of coefficients shouldn't matter to a neural network. Just drop the coefficients you don't want, and use what's left in whatever order is most convenient.